# Working with cookies and jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies

Today I decided to get to understand cookies better. The easiest way seemed jQuery. I used carhartl's [Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js).

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/Y3pjm/3/).

Basically, what I want is: when a user clicks the 'X', the pop-up closes (works fine) and a cookie is written so that the next time that user hits that page, he doesn't see the pop-up again!

```
function showPopUp() {
    var popUpMT = -($("#popUp").height() / 2) - 50;
    $("#popUp").css("marginTop", popUpMT).fadeIn("slow");
    $("#overlay").fadeIn("fast");
}

function setCookie() {
    $("#popUp").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#overlay").fadeOut("fast");
    $.cookie("popUpCookie", {
        expires: 365
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ourCookie = $.cookie("popUpCookie");
    if (ourCookie === null) {
        showPopUp();
    }

    $("#popUp span#close").click(function() {
        setCookie();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `setCookie` function, add some value as second argument as shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md).

```
$.cookie("popUpCookie", "true", { expires: 365});
```

In your fiddle, you only pass in the name and a settings object. Other than the it should work and does for me in [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3pjm/7/).

Comment: Thanks! I did not know a value was obligatory. Also +1 for a more logical function order!

Comment: See [line 24 of the cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/2e12796f574f0d842aa1025d38b04111852ae074/jquery.cookie.js#L24). Only if the `value` argument is given and not an object, the code to set the cookie is executed.